# How can I import the sqlite3 module into Python 2.4?

Tags: python, sqlite

The sqlite3 module is included in Python version 2.5+. However, I am stuck with version 2.4. I uploaded the sqlite3 module files, added the directory to sys.path, but I get the following error when I try to import it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in ?
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 26, in ?
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

The file '_sqlite3' is in lib-dynload, but if I include this in the sqlite3 directory, I get additional errors.

Any suggestions? I am working in a limited environment; I don't have access to GCC, among other things.

Comment: Install `libsqlite3-dev`

Source: http://superuser.com/questions/122140/problem-with-installing-sqlite3-module-for-python-2-6-on-an-ubuntu-system

Answer (score 13):

I had same problem with CentOS and python 2.4

My solution:

```
yum install python-sqlite2
```

and try following python code

```
try:
    import sqlite3
except:
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
```

Comment: One can install sqlite in Python 2.4 regardless of the Linux distribution with `easy_install pysqlite` (just take care not to mix your system packages with Python packages - i.e. just do the easy install in a virtualenv, or if the package does not exist for your linux). The import sequence on this answer is fine afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install it?  That often works better than messing with `sys.path`.

```
python setup.py install
```

If so, you should then find it.

If, for some reason, you can't install it, set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  Do not make a habit of messing with `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install [pysqlite](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite/). Notice, however, that this absolutely does require a compiler, unless you can find binaries for it (and Python 2.4) on the net. Using the 2.5 binaries will not be possible.

Comment: Since I don't have a compiler, this won't be possible. I was hoping that Python was more portable; I'll have to continue to interface with SQLite using the command line.

Answer (score -2):

You must ensure your sqlite, sqlite-devel, python-sqlite are installed correctly first and then  recompile Python.

Comment: You shouldn't have to recompile the Python install to fix this issue...simply reinstalling the sqlite, sqlite-devel, and python-sqlite should suffice. Unless, of course, you meant "run the script again".