# problems with python 2.7.3 on Centos with sqlite3 module

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, centos

i'm tying to play with sqlite3 on my centos server but it reports always the same error (module installed)....

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 29 2012, 19:03:18) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

on ubuntu and so on works fine.... any ideas of what i'm missing here?

---

i recompile the 2.7.3 again and it catch the sqlite3 libs well.

Comment: Have you installed the `python-sqlite` module?

Comment: This question might help:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789030/how-can-i-import-the-sqlite3-module-into-python-2-4][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789030/how-can-i-import-the-sqlite3-module-into-python-2-4

Comment: Well, those questions were for 2.4.... i recompile the 2.7.3 again and it catch the sqlite3 libs well. +1 for the search :) thanks.

Comment: If you found a solution, post it as an answer and accept it so others who find this question can see the solution as well.

Comment: a self explanatory phrase : "i recompile the 2.7.3 again..." :)

Answer (score 16):

If you are under RHEL/centos 6, you can try this:

```
cp /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/
```

Answer (score 6):

This will work for CentOS:

`ln -s /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/`

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` is already on python's path. No need to duplicate the file or add the python's path.

Answer (score 2):

first find:

```
find / -name _sqlite3.so
/usr/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
/usr/local/service/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
```

next

```
cp /usr/local/service/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/
```

this centso 6.5 python2.7.10

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 2.7.3 on a Red Hat 5 or CentOS 5 machine, there was a bug that prevented the SQLite modules from compiling properly when building Python from source; you should see an error message when running `make`.  It's since been fixed in 2.7.4 so your best option is to upgrade.

If that's not possible, then there's a patch available.  Here's the [bug page and the patch](http://bugs.python.org/issue14572).