# No module named sqlite

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

i am a beginner i need to create a python virtual_environment for installing Django. I am using the following steps for installing python and virtualenv

```
cd /usr/src/
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1./Python-3.5.1.tgz
tar zxf Python-3.5.1.tgz
cd python-3.5.1
mkdir /usr/local/python-3.5
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python'.$python.' --with-threads --enable-shared --with-zlib=/usr/include && make && make altinstall
echo "/usr/local/python3.5/lib" > python3.5.conf
mv python3.5.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python3.5.conf
/sbin/ldconfig
ln -sfn /usr/local/python3.5/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3.5
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-11.3.1.tar.gz
tar xzf setuptools-11.3.1.tar.gz
cd setuptools-11.3.1
/usr/local/python3.5/bin/python3.5 setup.py install
/usr/local/python3.5/bin/easy_install-3.5 pip
ln -sfn /usr/local/python3.5/bin/pip3.5 /usr/bin/pip3.5
/usr/local/python3.5/bin/pip3.5 install virtualenv
```

then i am created a virtualenv based on this,
and enter into python shell and use

```
import sqlite
```

i got following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'sqlite'
```

And i tried to run a django project installed in the virtalenv i got following errors.

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named '_sqlite3'
```

I am using CentOS release 6.8 (Final).

Comment: [Check other solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394013/problems-with-python-2-7-3-on-centos-with-sqlite3-module) it may be help you!!

Answer (score 3):

The python-bundled sqlite package is called `sqlite3`:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html

So, just do

```
import sqlite3
```

and you should be good.

**EDIT**

I only now realized that you're building python yourself. So that's probably why the sqlite3 module is missing. Check the output of the configure call whether sqlite3 is mentioned.
I assume you'd have to get the development packages.

Comment: Python 3.5.1 (default, Oct  5 2016, 06:38:10) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you are not using the [EPEL Repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) to install python?